# Get all resolutions of Apple devices?

Tags: applications, camera, resolution

I am building an app for in the App store.
For the app I need the resolution of the camera.
I am searching for the resolution of:

**iphone** 4 and up (front and back)
**Ipad** 2 and up (front and back)
**ipod** touch 5 gen. (front and rear)
**ipad** mini 1 and up (front and rear)

On the internet it is hard to found all this information. Is there some sort of site with this kind of information?

Comment: https://www.apple.com/iphone/compare/ here's iPhone5C and up. Here are iPads: https://www.apple.com/ipad/compare/

Comment: As an Apple developer, can't you use the Apple developer forums and technical documentation for getting this information?

Comment: there are so many sheets out there for display resolutions, I can't believe that it is "hard to find".

Comment: @YoshiBotX Please read next time. For display resolution there is even an site for that:http://iphoneresolution.com/ . I was asking for the resolution of the CAMERA that is a lot harder to find. Not the MP but the pixels (like 1920x1080). If that was the reason to give me -1 please correct that.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of informations can be found on **Wikipedia**.

Here's list of iOS devices with all the specs: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_iOS_devices

Here's simple MP calculator if You want to know pixel dimensions (it depends on aspect ratio): http://web.forret.com/tools/megapixel_aspect.asp?mp=3,15

Comment: Most of the resolution are listed in MP. If I convert the MP to resolution like 1920x1080 does I get the right resolution? Can I convert MP to pixels? And how do I get the aspect ratio?

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for that, but if I don't know what the aspect ratio of the camera is how do I know the resolution?

Comment: iPhone photos are 4:3 as far as I know. Additional question: why do you need to know all those infos? When You get an image You can check it's pixel size.